# Orthogonal contrasts and the poly function in R: Interpreting the coefficients as "absolute" or "incremental" effects

Tags: mixed-model, interpretation, polynomial, growth-model

in a growth curve like model, I try to test whether a trajectory (over time) is better described by a linear or quadratic trend. I fitted a linear mixed model (time nested in participants) and called orthogonal polynomial contrasts using the poly() function in R:

*mod <- lmerTest::lmer(outcome ~ poly(time, 2) + (poly(time, 2) | id), data=dat.long)*
*parameters::parameters(mod)* returns the following output:

| Parameter | Coefficient | SE | 95% CI | t(1215) | p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 6.75 | 0.15 | [ 6.46, 7.04] | 45.35 | < .001 |
| Time [1st degree] | -58.01 | 4.08 | [-66.01, -50.02] | -14.22 | < .001 |
| Time [2nd degree] | -9.00 | 2.56 | [-14.02, -3.98] | -3.51 | < .001 |

I now wonder which of the following interpretations is correct:
(1) The test statistics refer to the **"absolute"** fit of the corresponding trends.
Thus, the linear model fits the data better (|t| lin > |t| qua) than the quadratic model.
(2) The quadratic term describes the **increment** of the quadratic model (vs. linear term only), thus suggesting that the quadratic model fits the data better (*t*(1215) = -3.51, p < .001).

(I suspect it is (2), but I would very much appreciate any comments/advice.)

Thank you so much for your help!

Marcel

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion.

You have fitted one model that has a fixed intercept, a linear term and a quadratic term, plus some random effects.

> (1) The test statistics refer to the "absolute" fit of the corresponding trends. Thus, the linear model fits the data better (|t| lin > |t| qua) than the quadratic model.

This does not make sense because you have not fitted two models.

> (2) The quadratic term describes the increment of the quadratic model (vs. linear term only), thus suggesting that the quadratic model fits the data better (t(1215) = -3.51, p < .001).

Again this does not make sense for the same reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer. If not, please let us know why. Also, if you haven't already, please consider upvoting it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful answer! To make sure I interpret the results correctly:
(1) Can the second row (i.e., 1st degree) be interpreted as a negative linear trend?
(2) Does the significance of the quadratic term mean that we should _not_ drop the quadratic component of the model?

I remember being tought that the first polynomial does not reflect a linear trend but the "velocity" at x = 0. Here, however, where orthogonal contrasts are used, the linear component remains the same, no matter whether this is the only component in the model or whether I add a quadratic term (see above).